# NoClassDefFoundError in a java program

Tags: java, exception

I compiled the program given below and it was fine. Both class files and the java file are on my Desktop folder. But when I run it using the command "java B" on my terminal from the Desktop, I get the exception as given below. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with it?

import java.util.*;

```
public class a<X> {
//code
}

class b{
//code
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Comment: Are you sure that B class is not in some subfolder/package? You need to enter a fully qualified name, ommitting the .class extension

Comment: yes, both classes are in the same folder.

Comment: What is the package name for class B?

Comment: I dont know..I just wrote the class B as given in the code

Comment: Do you have access to the ImmutableQueue code?

Answer (score 1):

- After you compile your code, you end up with .class files for each class in your program. These binary files are the bytecode that Java interprets to execute your program. The NoClassDefFoundError indicates that the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the .class file for the class that you're trying to use. It probably indicates that you haven't set the classpath option when executing your code
- for more help see [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-%26-Run-Java-Program-Using-Command-Prompt)